# How can I get the AppStore URL of a macOS app by parsing the embedded MASReceipt?

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore

I need to obtain a list of URLs for AppStore apps on a number of systems. I'm vaguely aware that the URL can be formulated by concatenating the string `https://apps.apple.com/app/id` + the numeric ProductID which is contained somewhere in the app bundle, under `../Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt`

Does anyone have a reliable method for parsing this file and extracting that app id attribute? Python3 would be preferred but any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some very old [code on GitHub](https://github.com/pudquick/pyMASreceipt). With some modifications, it works. I tried it on a few app store apps that I have, and it succeeded in getting the appIds for all of them.

It needs python3 + asn1 module installed

```
pip install asn1
```

then save below as `appstore-url.py` and run e.g.:

```
$ appstore-url.py /Applications/Keynote.app
https://apps.apple.com/app/id409183694
```

code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Parses _MASReceipt/receipt and outputs an App Store URL

requires asn1 module:
  pip install asn1

original:
  https://github.com/pudquick/pyMASreceipt

refs:
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/validating_receipts_on_the_device
  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

"""

import asn1
import os
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
import argparse

MASAttr = namedtuple('MASAttr', 'type version value')

MAS_TYPES = {
    1: 'Product ID',
    2: 'Bundle Identifier',
    3: 'Application Version',
    4: 'Opaque Value',
    5: 'SHA-1 Hash',
    8: 'Purchase Date',
    10: 'Parental Content Rating',
    16: 'App Store Installer Version ID',
    17: 'In-App Purchase Receipt'
}

def unwind(input):
    ret_val = []
    while not input.eof():
        tag = input.peek()
        if tag[1] == 0x00:
            tag, value = input.read()
            ret_val.append((tag[2], tag[0], value))
        elif tag[1] == 0x20:
            ret_val.append((tag[2], tag[0]))
            input.enter()
            ret_val.append(unwind(input))
            input.leave()
    return ret_val

def extract_data(asn1_seq):
    ret_val = []
    for i, x in enumerate(asn1_seq):
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            if len(x) == 3 and x[2] == '1.2.840.113549.1.7.1':
                ret_val.append(asn1_seq[i + 2][0][2])
        elif isinstance(x, list):
            sub_val = extract_data(x)
            if isinstance(sub_val, list):
                ret_val.extend(sub_val)
            else:
                ret_val.append(sub_val)
    return ret_val[0] if len(ret_val) == 1 else ret_val

def parse_receipt(rec):
    ret_val = []
    for y in [z for z in rec if isinstance(z, list)]:
        try:
            dec = asn1.Decoder()
            dec.start(y[2][2])
            ret_val.append(MASAttr(MAS_TYPES.get(y[0][2], f'0x{y[0][2]:02X}'), y[1][2], unwind(dec)[0][-1]))
        except asn1.Error as e:
            #print(f"ASN.1 decoding error: {e}", file=sys.stderr)
            ret_val.append(MASAttr(MAS_TYPES.get(y[0][2], f'0x{y[0][2]:02X}'), y[1][2], y[2][2]))
    return ret_val

def get_app_receipt(path_to_MAS_app):
    receipt_path = os.path.join(path_to_MAS_app, "Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt")
    if not os.path.isfile(receipt_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"Receipt file not found: {receipt_path}")
    with open(receipt_path, 'rb') as f:
        dec1 = asn1.Decoder()
        dec1.start(f.read())
        payload = extract_data(unwind(dec1))
        dec2 = asn1.Decoder()
        dec2.start(payload)
        return parse_receipt(unwind(dec2)[1])

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Extracts ProductID and returns an AppStore URL by parsing the MASReceipt.")
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Path to the MAS app")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        decoded_receipt = get_app_receipt(args.path)
        for p in decoded_receipt:
            if p.type == 'Product ID':
                print(f'https://apps.apple.com/app/id{p.value}')
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error: {e}", file=sys.stderr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This actually works! Tested on my M1 Mac Mini 2020, Sonoma 14.1.1 + Python 3.11 from Homebrew.